# `capitalize` capitalizes letters following an apostrophe

Tags: capitalization

I wrote an Elisp script to deal with some file names with English phrases. `capitalize` converts "I'm a cat" to "I'M A Cat".

What's the right way to get the desired result? ("I'm A Cat") Should I use regex and write my own capitalization function?

Comment: capitalize forwards to the next word, so the issue is probably with the syntax table for the current mode, where word boundaries are specified.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2):

What mode is your file in? If I open `file.txt` (which according to my `auto-mode-alist` makes the major mode of the file `text`), then the `m` after the apostrophe is *not* capitalized either by `capitalize-region` or by `capitalize-word`. That follows from the fact that the syntax class of the apostrophe is `word`  in text mode, so `I'm` is considered a single "word", and only the `I` gets capitalized.

In other modes, the syntax class of the apostrophe may be different, leading to different capitalization behavior. For example, if you do the same thing with a file called `foo.py`, the file is opened in `python-mode` (at least with my settings in `auto-mode-alist`) and the syntax class of the apostrophe is `"` (i.e. it delimits quoted strings). That makes the `I` and the `m` separate "words", so each gets capitalized.

To find out the syntax class of a character in your buffer, put the cursor on it and say `C-u C-x =`, then look for `Syntax` in the description.

To find out more about syntax tables, do `C-h i g (elisp) Syntax tables`.

Comment: Interesting. I understand your point. I was reading a string from the minibuffer prompt using the `interactive` code letter `M` and then passing it to the `capitalize` function. This is inside an elisp utility function that I wrote.

Comment: This is what I get: `syntax: '  which means: prefix` for apostrophe in `emacs-lisp-mode`. How do I get it to work? This is the piece of code where it happens: `(string-join (mapcar #'capitalize (split-string title " ")) "_")`

Comment: I figure it out. Thanks. I used this: `(modify-syntax-entry ?\' "w")`